# React Component using codemirror not sending all data on form submission

Tags: django, reactjs, codemirror, react-codemirror

I am using django, react and react-codemirror2 in my project where a user can input SQL code. I am running into an issue where only part of the text from textarea exists in request.POST. I am finding that mostly just part of the last line of the textarea is sent. I am baffled.

**React component**

```
import React from 'react'
import {UnControlled as CodeMirror} from 'react-codemirror2'
import DjangoCSRFToken from 'django-react-csrftoken'

class SQLForm extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount() {
        let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]
        textarea.setAttribute('name', 'sql');
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <DjangoCSRFToken/>
                    <CodeMirror
                      options={{
                        mode: 'text/x-mssql',
                        theme: 'material',
                        lineNumbers: true
                      }}
                      onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
                      }}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SQLForm
```

**super simple django view** (just to see what is submitted)

```
def index(request):
    if 'sql' in request.POST:
        print(request.POST['sql'])
        return render(request, 'react.html', {})
    else:
        return render(request, 'react.html', {})
```

for example, in the text area, if type in the following

```
SELECT *
FROM whatever
WHERE something=2
```

print(request.POST['sql']) shows the following at the console

```
=2
```

And for completeness, this is the textarea tag when the page loads

```
<textarea autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: absolute; bottom: -1em; padding: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 1em; outline: none;" tabindex="0" name="sql"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got this to work by not worrying about CodeMirror being in the form. Instead I used state to capture the last *value* from the CodeMirror onChange function and then assigned that to the value attribute of the button. Switched the name attribute being in the textarea to being in the button itself.

```
import React from 'react'
import {UnControlled as CodeMirror} from 'react-codemirror2'
import DjangoCSRFToken from 'django-react-csrftoken'

class SQLForm extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.updateText = this.updateText.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            sql_text: ''
        }
    }

    updateText(value){
        this.setState((prevState)=>({sql_text:value}))
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <CodeMirror
                      options={{
                        mode: 'text/x-mssql',
                        theme: 'material',
                        lineNumbers: true
                      }}
                      onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
                          {this.updateText(value)}
                      }}
                 />
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <DjangoCSRFToken/>
                    <button type="submit" value={this.state.sql_text} name="sql">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SQLForm
```